# MapKit 3.3.1 проблема с zoom

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

столкнулся с проблемой при реализации зума программными средствами на андроиде. Если в двух словах, то сделал наложение с кнопками поверх карты и при нажатии должен меняться зум, но ничего не происходит. Вот фрагмент кода:

```
mapButtonZoomPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mZoom += 1;
            Log.d(TAG, "mapButtonZoomPlus click");
            CameraPosition lCameraPosition = new CameraPosition(map.getMapWindow().getMap().getCameraPosition().getTarget(), mZoom, 0f, 0f);
            com.yandex.mapkit.Animation lAnimation = new com.yandex.mapkit.Animation(com.yandex.mapkit.Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 0.3f);
            map.getMapWindow().getMap().move(lCameraPosition, lAnimation, null);
        }
    });
```

getMapWindow() убирал, но результат нулевой. При этом пальцами зум настраивается замечательно. Подскажите в чём может быть причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался в причине. Оказывается в моем случае почему-то было необходимо после рендера вьюшки с картой вызвать метод OnStart() у самой вью:  `mapVew.onStart();`

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, неверное значение mZoom, и лучше писать так:

```
CameraPosition lCameraPosition = new CameraPosition(map.getCameraPosition().getTarget(), map.getCameraPosition().getZoom() + 1, map.getCameraPosition().getAzimuth(), map.getCameraPosition().getTilt());
```